# Applescript to copy/sync dropped folders to a destination folder

Tags: macos, finder, applescript

Hello using Applescript on Macos I want to copy/sync dropped folders (onto the applescript app) to a predefined destination folder.

I  have this script I've written, but it's not working:

```
on open theFiles
    tell application "Finder"
        set destFolder to "/Users/Username/Desktop/My Files"
        do shell script "/usr/bin/rsync -a  'theFiles' 'destFolder' "
    end tell
end open
```

Can anyone please help fix my script to work? Thanks much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update 2:

This should work with both dropped files and folders.

```
-- shell command
-- /usr/bin/rsync -a '/Users/username/Documents/few/moo Files' '/Users/username/Documents/few/stopple' '/Users/username/Desktop/My Files/'

-- applescript resolved and expanded
-- do shell script "/usr/bin/rsync -a '/Users/username/Documents/few/moo Files' '/Users/username/Documents/few/stopple' '/Users/username/Desktop/My Files/'"
```

### Script 3:

```
on open belF
    
    tell application "Finder"
        set destFolder to quoted form of ((POSIX path of (path to desktop) as text) & "My Files")
        set til to {}
        
        -- set belF to selection -- for troubleshooting
        repeat with i in belF -- alias of each dropped file/folder
            set aNom to name of i
            set aCon to container of i as alias
            set aPat to aCon & aNom as text
            set ppa to POSIX path of aPat
            copy quoted form of ppa to end of til -- posix path of every dropped file/folder
        end repeat
    end tell
    
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to space
    set ti to til as text
    -- display dialog ti -- for troubleshooting
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}
    
    do shell script "/usr/bin/rsync -a " & ti & space & destFolder
    
end open
```

Comment: Actually I’d like to drop any folders onto the applescript app icon and it should be synced with a preset destination folder

Comment: So if you drop two folders, then the destFolder will end up with each folder along with their contents?

Comment: Yes exactly you are correct

Comment: And will you 'only' drop folders? So the selection will contain zero files (but any folder can contain files)?

Comment: Yes correct again just folders with content in them

Comment: Okay, same basic premise. Let me think about it.

Comment: Note that the Finder (or System Events) is not needed at all, unless you are going to do something like add a comparison for the class of a dropped item (since it can also be a file).

Comment: @red_menace You're right. Initially I'd written it using the Finder selection. I will probably edit it later today.

Comment: @Mockman In the script you've written, where do I set the destFolder ?

Comment: The last line before 'do shell'. But you could move that anywhere in the script as long as it is before the 'do shell'. You could use choose folder to select it as well, as long as the result has the same form.

Comment: Thanks is there any modification to allow even files to work?

Comment: My pleasure. I think the original script I wrote worked on files.

Comment: I think the original script has been edited?

Comment: You can always click on the 'clock' icon below a post to see its history. For questions, there is also a 'bookmark' feature.

Comment: Okay… revised to work on both files and folders.

Comment: Thanks i will try and revert back here

Comment: Many thanks, yes your final script works very well. I am grateful to you! :)

Comment: Glad that it worked out. My pleasure.